Serializing & Deserializing Data from Firebase in C# Unity not working
I am trying to deserialize the same object I serialized to Firebase Realtime database but am running into an issue getting it to work. Here's the class/script breakdown:
[Serializable]
public class PuzzleSphereTarget
{
    public Nullable<float> x;
    public Nullable<float> y;
    public Nullable<float> z;

    public PuzzleSphereTarget()
    {
        this.x = null;
        this.y = null;
        this.z = null;
    }
    public PuzzleSphereTarget(float xParam, float yParam, float zParam)
    {
        this.x = xParam;
        this.y = yParam;
        this.z = zParam;
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }

}

As well as a wrapper PuzzleSphereInformation class:
[Serializable]
public class PuzzleSphereInformation
{
    public string creatorName { get; set; }
    public List<PuzzleSphereTarget> puzzleSphereTarget { get; set; }

    public PuzzleSphereInformation()
    {
        this.creatorName = null;
        this.puzzleSphereTarget = new List<PuzzleSphereTarget>();
    }
    public PuzzleSphereInformation(string creatorName, List<PuzzleSphereTarget> puzzleSphereTarget)
    {
        this.creatorName = creatorName;
        this.puzzleSphereTarget = puzzleSphereTarget;
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }

}

How I'm saving:
// creatorName: string, puzzleTargets: List<PuzzleSphereTarget>
private void SavePuzzle(creatorName, puzzleTargets)
    PuzzleSphereInformation puzzleInfo = new PuzzleSphereInformation(creatorName, puzzleTargets);
    string puzzleInfoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(puzzleInfo);
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference($"/community_puzzles/").Push().SetRawJsonValueAsync(puzzleInfoJson);
}

Object in fireBase:
{"creatorName":"test user","puzzleSphereTarget":[{"x":-0.2674436,"y":0.009597826,"z":0.894937754},{"x":0.2539144,"y":0.00647806656,"z":0.8653086}]}
When I try to deserialize the same object, it's blank and I don't know why (this is the correct firebase db layer to retrieve the data):
_databaseReference.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
    //// omitted firebase code ////
            foreach (DataSnapshot targetInfo in targetSnapshot.Children)
            {
                string puzzleDataJson = targetInfo.GetRawJsonValue();
                PuzzleSphereInformation puzzleInformation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PuzzleSphereInformation>(puzzleDataJson);
                Debug.Log("creatorName" + puzzleInformation.creatorName); // nothing
            }
    //// omitted fb code////
});

What am I doing wrong in this case? I am trying to deserialize the same object I serialized and no luck. Thx for any help
I've tried JsonUtility.FromJson, JsonConvert and neither has worked.

I looked again at deserializing part and found a fix! Turns out instead of targetSnapshot.GetRawJsonValue(), what I needed was: targetSnapshot.Value.ToString().
After this change, the deserialization worked fine
